# Where is the job's detail log in cdh4 hadoop?

Tags: logging, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, cloudera

I just find jobhistory in hdfs

```
/home/mps/cdh/users/history/done_intermediate/mps/job_1405497023620_0009-1405505656182-mps-simjoin%2D1.0.jar-1405505683781-0-0-FAILED-default.jhist
```

But this jobhistory information is far from detail like this:

```
{"type":"TASK_FAILED","event":{"org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.jobhistory.TaskFailed":{"taskid":"task_1405497023620_0008_m_000002","taskType":"MAP","finishTime":1405505044309,"error":", \n","failedDueToAttempt":{"string":"attempt_1405497023620_0008_m_000002_3"},"status":"FAILED"}}}
```

Where can I find more detail info like Exceptions throw or log info logger by the job's logger in Mapper and Reducer?

Answer (score 0):

Check this directory: (According to your setup)

```
/var/log/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/userlogs/job_201407151208_0031/attempt_201407151208_0031_m_000000_0
```

You will find

- Stdout
- Stderr
- Syslog

In these files you will find job's execution in detail.